# remove table row when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

A table row will be removed if the remove row button is clicked.

A new field and remove row button will be added to the table body if the add button is clicked.

The problem I am facing is that the remove row button works in my html but not in my javascript. Please help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Page 2</title>

</head>

<body>
  <table id="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Field 1
          <input type="text" name="field1">
        </td>
        <td>

          <button class="btn removemebtn">Remove Row!</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button class="btn" id="addbtn">Add</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
      .ready(
        function() {
          $('#addbtn')
            .click(
              function() {
                $('tbody')
                  .append(
                    '<tr>' + '<td>' + 'Field 2 <input type="text" name="field2">' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<button class="btn removemebtn">Remove Row!!' + '</button>' + '</td>'

                    + '</tr>');
              });

          $('.removemebtn').click(function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
          });
        });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having occurs because you're setting an event listener for `.removebtn` at `$(document).ready ({/*..*/})` so when you remove your row, the new button wont have the same event listener.

Wrap your remove functionality into a function and set an onclick attribute on each row that calls that function.